Jenkins - Throttle concurrent build depending on executor and workspace
I'm trying to find a solution to control the execution of different jobs like so:
I have a bunch of machines that all have the same workspace format > Jenkins/workspace/W1
All the jobs use the same workspace, and can run on all the machines, but there should only be one job running on the same machine at once.
So for example:
Machines: B1, B2, B3 (all have a workspace named W1);
Jobs: J1, J2
J1 is triggered on B1 - should run;
J2 is triggered on B2 - should run, because workspace W1 is available on B2;
J1 is triggered on B3 - should run, because workspace W1 is available on B3;
J2 is triggered on B1 - should wait for execution of J1, because W1 is not available on B1
So basically I need to control the throttling of builds depending on the workspace availability of a machine, not on the job. I know the default behavior of Jenkins is to create W2 in case W1 is not available and that is something I want to avoid 100%.

You can configure a Jenkins agent to only have one executor, so no two jobs can be executed on that agent at the same time. Here is a good CloudBees writeup on that.
Update: if you want to get more granular
There is a lockable-resources plugin that can help you with locking a workspace at the expense of some manual maintenance overhead.
First you would need to create as many resources as you have non-sharable workspaces and give them the same names as your agents - B1, B2, and B3. Then assign them the same label, for example W1, making them interchangeable. You could use them like this in a pipeline:
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                lock (resource: null, label: 'W1', quantity: 1, variable: 'nodeName') {
                    echo "Assigned to resource ${nodeName}"
                    node(nodeName) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

You will have to create and delete those resources as you add and remove agents.

do you think that's the only solution? I would still like to be able to run other jobs on that machine, as long as it's not affecting that specific workspace. Could I have two agents on the same machine?
